# Can FB Graphi API see interaction with my fan page content

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a website, and a Facebook fan page for said website. My website is using Facebook connect and I was wondering if it's possible to query the number of likes, shares, and comments of my fan page content that originated from the logged in users.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done by crawling your page's feed via the [graph api](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) and collecting the comments and likes of the [posts](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) (see connections part) on your own database. However it's a pretty big undertaking, you will have to deal with synchronization of content (deleting posts from your side when its deleted on facebook), expiring access tokens, occasional facebook outages and so on.

If you just want to show content to the users they might like on your page facebook gives you a social plugin called [Recommendations](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/recommendations/) for that.